# How can I make ".." to go to parent directory like "cd.." in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to be able to type ".." to go to parent directory, instead of "cd..". Is this possible in Windows command prompt?

Comment: Possible in a powershell command prompt but not in the classic legacy command prompt.  Windows 10 as of 1703 by default uses the powershell command prompt.

Comment: There is something called New-Alias cmdlet and in theory you could make a an alias to your own comma called `..` although that is likely to a problem because of PowerShell syntax rules now now that I think about it some more.

Comment: You could use `set ..=cd ..` and then you could use `%..%` I suppose if that'd suffice. See screen shot here of me testing this: https://i.imgur.com/vSMW9Ax.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could use `doskey.exe` for that. It's been available in any recent os versions (and not so recent... DOS 6.22). Always available, little known - provides history, among other features.
`doskey ..=cd ..`

```
C:\temp>..
C:\>
```

Technet reference https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753867(v=ws.11).aspx

To make this macro permanent, you'd need to setup in via Autorun.
From `help cmd`

> If /D was NOT specified on the command line, then when CMD.EXE starts, it
>   looks for the following REG_SZ/REG_EXPAND_SZ registry variables, and if
>   either or both are present, they are executed first.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

    and/or

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

Comment: Doskey... why didn't I think of that... good idea +1

Answer (score 3):

Not with **cmd.exe** alone. Even if you successfully create file `..`**.bat**, it won't be recognized and called when you type `..` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But you can achieve this, however. If you install free [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) tool, the following macro sends expected command whenever you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> (only in window which has `cmd.exe` in title):

```
#IfWinActive cmd.exe

F9::
^up::Send {Esc}cd..{Enter}

F12::
^+up::Send {Esc}cd{asc 92}{Enter}

#IfWinActive
```

Tested, works well.

**Edit:**

Bonus: I extended the macro.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or simply <kbd>F9</kbd> does `cd..`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or simply <kbd>F12</kbd> does `cd\`
- I did not map keys between <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd>, because they are already in use in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: You should delete. wmz pulled off the exact request.

Comment: @Joshua – Do you mean delete the answer? I think it has its value although it is not exact. For someone, pressing single key is a vital innovation instead of typing dot+dot+Enter. I also added F12 for going to the root. And F10 is still available for further adding of custom functionality (F11 is in use).